# How do I get all values in array of objects if hashMap has same key name

Tags: javascript, json, hashmap

I have a JSON structure and code like below :

```
const villages = 
    {
    "lossesOccured":
        [
            {
                "type": "destroyed",
                "affectedOn": "humans",
                "quantity": 120,
                "reliefFund": 100000,
                "location": {
                    "district": "thanjavur",
                    "villageName": "madukkur",
                    "pincode": "614903"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "physicalDamage",
                "affectedOn": "humans",
                "quantity": 250,
                "reliefFund": 50000,
                "location": {
                    "district": "thanjavur",
                    "villageName": "madukkur",
                    "pincode": "614903"
                }
            }
         ]
    }

const losses = villages.lossesOccured

const myMap = new Map()
const humanMap = new Map()

losses.forEach((data,index) => {
    var keys = data.affectedOn
    var objJSON = new Object();
    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        objJSON[keys] = data;
       }
       myMap.set(objJSON,data)
});

function extactLosses(){
    myMap.forEach(loss => {
        if(loss.affectedOn === "humans"){
            humanMap.set(loss.affectedOn,[loss])
     }

for (var [key, value] of humanMap) {
    console.log(key , value);
 }
```

From the above code,since there are same key names(affectedOn) in many elements, map eliminates all duplicates and prints only one in the output.
Is there a way to print the key as string and value as array of objects without eliminating the ones with the same key name.
Thanks in advance.

Output:
[image: Map]

Expected Output
[image: Expected]

Comment: Can you clarify what output you are looking for?  Using your input as an example, what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: Sure, i have added a image of the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just want to filter the lossesOccurred array to pull out the ones that were human losses.

```js
const villages = 
    {
    "lossesOccured":
        [
            {
                "type": "destroyed",
                "affectedOn": "humans",
                "quantity": 120,
                "reliefFund": 100000,
                "location": {
                    "district": "thanjavur",
                    "villageName": "madukkur",
                    "pincode": "614903"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "physicalDamage",
                "affectedOn": "humans",
                "quantity": 250,
                "reliefFund": 50000,
                "location": {
                    "district": "thanjavur",
                    "villageName": "madukkur",
                    "pincode": "614903"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "physicalDamage",
                "affectedOn": "NOT humans",
                "quantity": 250,
                "reliefFund": 50000,
                "location": {
                    "district": "thanjavur",
                    "villageName": "madukkur",
                    "pincode": "614903"
                }
            }
         ]
    };
    
const humanLosses = villages.lossesOccured.filter(loss => loss.affectedOn == 'humans');

console.log(humanLosses);
```

Comment: You can't have multiple "same keys" in a hashmap.  One of each.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you, i have kept the value as humanLosses and key as affectedOn. Now it works fine.